# Printing UI: Specified Visual is already a child of another Visual or the root of a CompositionTarget

Tags: c#, wpf, printing, visual-studio-2013

So I built a WYSIWYG editor that allows users to drag and drop controls on a canvas. Then, after having it arranged how they'd like, they can print the template out.

I am running into some issues with the Visual tree though.

XAML

```
  <Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width=".2*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width=".8*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <StackPanel AllowDrop="False" Background="Gray">
      <!--REMOVED-->
    </StackPanel>
    <Canvas Grid.Column="1" AllowDrop="True" Width="600" Height="800"                 
            Background="White" x:Name="CanvasControl" 
            DataContext="{Binding CanvasVM}" 
            DragEnter="CanvasFlowDocument_DragEnter" 
            DragLeave="CanvasFlowDocument_DragLeave" 
            DragOver="CanvasFlowDocument_DragOver" 
            Drop="CanvasFlowDocument_Drop"/>
  </Grid>
```

C#

```
private void PrintCanvas()
{
   //Prompt for print
   PrintDialog pd = new PrintDialog();
   if (pd.ShowDialog()==true)
   {
       //Trying to use flow document for printing because I need to be able to control 
       //how the margins look on the page
       FlowDocument CanvasFlowDocument = new FlowDocument();
       BlockUIContainer buiCont = new BlockUIContainer();   

       //Get the parent of the CanvasControl because I can't pass the CanvasControl to my
       //Printer until it doesn't have a logical visual parent             
       Grid par = (Grid)CanvasControl.Parent;
       par.Children.Remove(CanvasControl);

       //Add Control to Block UI Container for printing
       buiCont.Child = CanvasControl;
       CanvasFlowDocument.Blocks.Add(buiCont);

        //Print the doc
       pd.PrintDocument((CanvasFlowDocument as IDocumentPaginatorSource).DocumentPaginator, "Template");

       //Now, in an attempt to re-add my canvas to the grid so my user can continue to see/manipulate it. I first clear the blocks
       CanvasFlowDocument.Blocks.Clear();

       //I even go as far as setting the Block UI Container child to null
       buiCont.Child = null;
       CanvasControl.UpdateLayout();

       //This is where explosions ensue...
       //The CanvasControl.Parent is null at this point, yet I still get the error below
       par.Children.Add(CanvasControl);
  }          
}
```

ERROR:

> Specified Visual is already a child of another Visual or the root of a
>   CompositionTarget

Comment: This is very interesting. Have you tried looking through the children on CanvasFlowDocument.Blocks to see if it's still in there?

Comment: Yeah, it's empty. I am so confused as to what is holding onto the reference.

Answer (score 0):

What I found out is that it's possible to have `Parent` property be NULL, but component is clearly attached to some Visual. In this case you need to use `var parentObject = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(child);`, which will reliably tell you visual parent. You can simply use the following snippet:

```
var parentObject = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(child);
if (parentObject != null)
{
    parentObject.Children.Remove(child);
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work.  `VisualTreeHelper.GetParent()` returns a `DependencyObject`, and there is no `Children` property on `DependencyObject`.